# register application in fitbit api

Tags: java, api, fitbit

How can I register application in fitbit api without real application ? Basically I want to access the users' data to know the structure of the data stream which I will use it in my application

It suppose to fill the application name and websites and I am not yet developed it.

what is the starting point to use the fitbit API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecessary to actually have an application built before you register it with Fitbit. You can change practically everything after you have created it.

You can't access data without fitbit's API client credentials. You will also need a Fitbit account. See the [docs](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs) for instruction.

You can do this from https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/new.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what my question was how I can fill the form of the registering new application with information I don't have it such as Application webpage , application organization ,, etc.. Should I fill it with any information not true ?

Comment: It's not validated, if that's what you mean. When I did it, I gave it information that I later changed.